# Cast Boolean constructor as a type guard

Tags: typescript, typeguards

It's common pattern to use the `Boolean` constructor in an array `.filter(/* ... */)` to filter out falsy values.

Is there anyway I can cast the `Boolean` constructor to a type guard that removes nullables? I'm trying to do something like below:

```
const list = ['foo', 'bar', null];

// how can I make this line not error?
const onlyStrings: string[] = list.filter(Boolean as <T>(t: T) => t is NonNullable<T>);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Conversion of type 'BooleanConstructor' to type '<T>(t: T) => t is NonNullable<T>' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other
```

Any ideas?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgS2jAvDA2gcgGYhJgGhkwCMBDAJ0JjAFc44BdAbgChXRJZw4BPAZSgUEYAOYRU8JFAB02BHCgBTCgAoAQnjhKyYGGQkAeACoA+VVABcMYwEpUpmLCQwAcuFf04ZEtpOnbNiA)

Comment: The error message likely says "If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first." So: `Boolean as unknown as <T>(t: T) => t is NonNullable<T>`... with caveats about how `NonNullable<T>` won't do the right thing with `""`, `0`, `NaN`, or `false`